# Disable OS X Enter Full Screen animation

Tags: macos, productivity, animation

Most applications have a hotkey for entering full-screen in OS X with <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd>, for others I created a keyboard shortcut for `Enter Full Screen` and `Exit Full Screen` in system preferences.

But the 3.0 seconds animation is extremely annoying!

How can I disable the OS X animation of windows going into full screen mode?

Comment: A similar question at Ask Different: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17440

Comment: Well i am sorry to say this but as i looked for you there is no way to turn it off

the only thing you can do is that tell Apple to fix your problem

Here are some urls that might help you

   http://www.apple.com/contact/
   http://www.apple.com/support/

Answer (score 2):

Navigate to:

`chrome://flags/`

Scroll down to find the one called "Enable simplified full screen" and disable it. Re-launch Chrome and you are finished.

[Source](http://www.reddit.com/r/apple/comments/1plzmq/)

*Disclaimer*

> Google Chrome - WARNING These experimental features may change, break or disappear at any time.

Comment: It disappeared :(

Comment: It is listed as "unavailable" on macOS High Sierra. It also doesn't answer the question, since the question was about general full-screen for applications and not specific to Google Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible, but i would reccomend using TotalSpaces as a replacement of Apple's bad implementation. http://totalspaces.binaryage.com

Comment: Excellent! Solves the problem of switching to other spaces perfectly. But the mission control and full-screen enter are still slow as hell.

Comment: @Evgeny The Mission Control animations can be disabled with `defaults write com.apple.dock expose-animation-duration -float 0; killall Dock`.

Comment: @LauriRanta it doesn't help with moving to other spaces. Only for moving in and out of mission control.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using OS X Lion try this:

To disable automatic window animations, open Terminal and type the command:

```
defaults write NSGlobalDomain NSAutomaticWindowAnimationsEnabled -bool NO
```

Found on this site:
http://www.chriswrites.com/2012/01/turn-off-animations-eye-candy-effects-in-mac-os-x-lion/

Which has instructions for turning off other animations as well, and a link to 'power toys' like the ones Lorenzo posted in his answer.

Comment: It doesn't affect the animations for entering and exiting full screen though.

Comment: odd... it seems that it should... not even after a reboot?  Dang, I wish my mac wasn't too old for os x... back to google